# How to iterate JSON with Laravel in Blade

Tags: json, laravel, mongodb, laravel-blade

I am starting to use Mongo with Laravel. I have managed to make the connection and execute the first added queries.
The question I have now is to iterate through the results with **foreach** in the **blade** template.

I go through a basic json file without problems

```
$json1 = '{
            "title":"Superman",
            "category": "Superhero"
          }';

return view('index', ['data' => $json1]);
```

On the blade:

```
  @foreach($data as $item)
       {{$item->title}}
       {{$item->category}}
       <br/>
  @endforeach
```

Now, how do I go through the following file:

```
$json2 = '{
    "tag":{
       "title":"title"
    }
}';

return view('index')->with('data', json_decode($json2));
```

I don't know how to access the **title** of the **tag**.

I have tried the following but without success.

```
@foreach($data as $item)
       {{$item->tag.title}}
        <br/>
@endforeach
```

Comment: `$item->tag->title` or `$item['tag']['title']`, most likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `json_decode` method returns a `stdClass` object (unless you provide `true` as the second parameter which returns an associative array).

So once you have decoded your JSON, you can access the properties as you would do so for any other class based property:

```
$json2 = '{
    "tag":{
       "title":"title"
    }
}';

$data = json_decode($json2);

return view('index', compact('data'));
```

```
@foreach ($data as $item)
    {{ $item->title }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks. It's very useful... But I would like to see how I should express it in a 'foreach' with 'blade'... If I iterate it in the template I get an error: "Undefined variable $decoded"...

Comment: @foreach($data as $item)
         {{ $item->$decoded->tag->title }}
         <br/>
 @endforeach

Comment: @AdolfiTéllez Please see my update.

Comment: Thanks. But sending it that way I get the error: "Undefined property: stdClass::$tag"

Comment: @AdolfiTéllez - Made a slight change to how you access title in the blade file.

Comment: It works perfectly. I appreciate it, friend...